# Cypress: How to get Href attribute value, redirect and match the URL with value

Tags: javascript, cypress, chaining

- Please open the image [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCYta.jpg)

I want to get the value (URL) of the first href for this class (.grid-item) then navigate to the respective href link and verify the value (URL) with the current page's URL.

How can I achieve that using Cypress?

Code:

```
  selectStackup = () => {
    cy.get(".grid-item")
      .eq(1)
      .invoke("attr", "href")
      .then(href => {
        cy.visit(href);
      });
  };
```

**Error:**
- CypressError: cy.visit() must be called with a URL or an options object containing a URL as its 1st argument

Comment: @Shubham updated

Answer (score 0):

Just add the prefix of your `baseUrl` from `cypress.json` OR `yourUrl.com` along with the `href` and should be fine.

```
cy.visit(`yourUrlOrBaseUrl.com${href}`);
```